# Executing java class in JAR from a java program

Tags: java, jar, mainclass

My Question is:

I have a test.java class which is the main class. There is one more class(non-main class) which is present in JAR file. Now i want to compile and execute demo class present in JAR from the main class present outside the JAR. Please explain why.

```
public class test
{   
public static void main(String args[])
{
    demo d1 = new demo();
    demo d2 = new demo("message passed from main class");
}
} 

public class demo
{
demo()}
System.out.println("message in demo class");
}
demo(String str)
{
System.out.println(str);
}}
```

Comment: *"Please explain how."*  Please explain ***why?***

Comment: Just a word on design, your classes should always start with a capita letter, so public class Test, public class Demo

Comment: Agree. I didn't much attention to that because I wanted to post sample code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the proper answer us 'use ant', but:

```
javac test.java
javac demo.java
jar cf test.jar test.class demo.class
jar ufe test.jar test
```

and then,

```
java -jar test.jar
```

If you intend to expand on this, and continue not to use ant, you'll likely want your build system to stop on an error, and will notice that 'javac' doesn't return non-zero on error.  Pipe its stderr to a temporary file and then quit depending on grep's non-zero return of that file. e.g., from an on-device build script that cannot use ant:

```
cd src
for F in R.java Maze.java EmptyActivity.java; do
  javac -d ../build/classes $P/$F 2> ~/tmp/javac.out
  echo -en "\033[1m"; cat ~/tmp/javac.out; echo -en "\033[0m"
  grep error ~/tmp/javac.out && exit
done
cd ..
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this: [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/)

Once you have both your main class and JAR file ready, you can simply run the main class with the JAR file on the classpath and Java will find it. Assuming the `demo` class is in `demo.jar` and your main class is `test` (as in your example):

```
java -cp demo.jar test
```

Comment: Its giving an exception saying exception in thread main. java.lang.Noclassdeffounderror:TEST.

Comment: in my demo.jar i have demo.class and demo.java. Outside i have test.java. I compiled test by "JAVAC TEST.JAVA -CLASSPATH DEMO.JAR". It was compiled successfully. Now i m trying to execute TEST by "JAVA -CP DEMO.JAR TEST"  and now its giving this exception.

Comment: Java is case-sensitive. If you defined the class as `test`, you need to run it as `test` and not `TEST`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply if you want to use any `class in java` then that class must be present in `class-path`
because when you run your program  then all `class` needed for that is always looking in `class path`..
So you have to set class-path  of your `demo.jar`
There is no of ways to set class path take a look of this [How set class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html)

or simply you can do another option use `java` parameter `-cp`

```
java -cp /your jar path/demo.jar test
```